# Odoo Email is 'Outbox' state. But mail is not received by the receiver

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-9, openerp-8

Email state is outbox. But mail is not received by the receiver. Outgoing mail Configuration also correct.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to check the email queue manager under technical->Automation->Scheduled Actions. to view this menus you have to enable developer mode.

[image]

This is an example email queue manager with interval of 30 mins. You can configure according to your needs.